# Simple macros in LLDB?

Tags: ios, swift, lldb

Is there a way to create simple macros in LLDB, without creating a dedicated plugin? For example, in iOS development, I frequently have to execute this specific string:

```
 e CATransaction.flush()
```

Is there something I can add to my `.lldbinit` that will let me just type:

```
 caflush
```

without having to write a plugin?

P.S. I'm aware of [Chisel](https://github.com/facebook/chisel) but it doesn't yet support Swift.

Comment: You're not using Xcode?

Comment: I go back and forth between Xcode and AppCode - why do you ask?

Comment: Ah, okay.  Just wasn't clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I figured this one out on my own after some deeper googling:

```
command alias caflush e CATransaction.flush()
```

does the trick.

Pretty simple!

Comment: You can also refer to the command's arguments with %1, %2, etc